# Error while testing login API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, authentication

I'm getting an error during testing the login API

POST /api/login 404 2.774 ms - 23

```
  app.post('/login',function(req,res){

    User.findOne({
      username:req.body.username
    }).select('password').exec(function(err,user){

      if(err) throw err;

      if(!user){
        res.send({message:"user doesnot exist"});
      }else if(user){
        var validPassword=user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
        if(!validPassword){
          res.send({message:"Invalid Password"});
        }else{
          var token=createToken(user);
          res.json({
            success:true,
            message:"Successfully login",
            token:token
          });
        }
      }
    });
 });
 return api
}
```

Comment: Did you define any middleware to add `api`?

Comment: Side note NEVER tell the client what's going on. always return with "the user name or password is incorrect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mentioned `api` in your route then you must add a middleware to add `api` something like this

> app.use('/api', require('you route'));

Or you have to `map` your route like this

```
    app.post('/api/login',function(req,res){

    User.findOne({
      username:req.body.username
    }).select('password').exec(function(err,user){

      if(err) throw err;

      if(!user){
        res.send({message:"user doesnot exist"});
      }else if(user){
        var validPassword=user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
        if(!validPassword){
          res.send({message:"Invalid Password"});
        }else{
          var token=createToken(user);
          res.json({
            success:true,
            message:"Successfully login",
            token:token
          });
        }
      }
    });
 });
```